How to make socket.io connection live forever i.e even when browser is minimised and the system is at sleep? On laptop and mobile as well
I developed a socket.io chat app with node.js that works fine with sending messages to rooms and all. I added notifications as well. But only one thing is missing. When the browser tab is inactive for long time or when it have been minimised for long or the laptop or mobile goes to sleep for some time. Then the connection is lost. I want to make it rigid. It should work like any other chat app. Should be just on all the time. Please help me find a solution for this.
I tried adding connection state recovery in options. Sending ping packets. But nothing works. After I come back I need to reload so that it is on well. Actually I observed that the socket rooms in the server side are being closed some time after browser is minimised. Can anyone please help? You can suggest alternatives too. Will server-sent events or long polling fullfill my requirement?
